# Send custom object and a string to other activity

Tags: android

I need send a custom object and a string to other activity. custom object(User) implemented Parcelable interface.
I do like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("action") ;
Bundle data = new Bundle() ;
data.putString("EDIT", "EDIT");
data.putParcelable("DATA", user ) ; //user is custom object
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", data) ;
startActivity(intent) ;
```

In other activity, I receive the intent, but the EDIT map data is null, only Pacelable data in  Intent, EDIT string missed.

```
Intent intent  = getIntent() ;
String edit = bundle.getString("EDIT") ;  // edit = null should be EDIT
Bundle bundle =intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE") ;
```

Anyone else developers know this issue, can you give me suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dude use it this way

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 intent.putExtra("foo ", foo);
 intent.putExtra("string", "hi");
 startActivity(intent);
```

To GET

```
 Foo foo = (Foo) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("foo");
 String mString =  getIntent().getStringExtra("string");
```

Comment: Serializable is a good choice but officially, Parcelable is the solution for these kinds of needs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: Hi Rstar, a string also should send to target activity with Foo. Do you have any other suggestions? ths!

Comment: Thanks very much!  I change the order of get from bundle. it works fine!.                                                                 
`code`Bundle bundle =intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE") ;  String edit = bundle.getString("EDIT") ;  // edit = null should be EDIT `code`

Comment: This problem must be related to the development environment. I run the older code, can it's fine now.